# Assigning a bound function to a std::function

Tags: c++, templates, vector, compiler-errors

This wont compile for me:

```
int i = 1;
std::function<void(std::vector<int>&)> execute = std::bind(append<int>, _1, std::ref(i));
```

Where append has the signature:

```
template<class T>
void append(std::vector<T>& container, const T& valueToAppend)
```

Is it obvious as to what I'm doing wrong?

The comiler error is:

```
error C2664: 'void (std::vector<_Ty> &,const T &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::arg<I>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              I=1
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
```

Comment: I think we are missing some information, like the headers you included and the using directives you wrote. For instance, your sample code never evoke Boost, but the message error seems to indicate that you are using one of its libraries.

Comment: Hm. Works fine in Visual Studio 2010. What compiler are you using? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
```